# Oddities in the election system message

Tags: support, status-completed, election

I am not sure if moderators can change the system message calling for voting, but if possible, please consider changing the current message:

> Cast your final vote in the Theoretical Computer Science 2011 community moderator election!

to something along

> Cast your vote in the Theoretical Computer Science 2011 community moderator election if you have at least 150 reputation points!

The proposed changes are:

- Primary proposal: Add “if you have at least 150 reputation points” because otherwise you are asking people with <150 rep points to do something you disallow, which is not nice.
- Secondary proposal: Change “final vote” to simply “vote” because we did not have the primary phase.

Related to the first item, a user of Meta Stack Overflow had proposed something similar in [Don't have Stack Overflow propose that I vote in the moderator election when I don't have the reputation to do so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76506/dont-have-stack-overflow-propose-that-i-vote-in-the-moderator-election-when-i-do).  Unlike that post, I am not asking to change the system message depending on the user’s reputation points.

Comment: @Suresh: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suresh seems to have changed the message appropriately.  Thanks, Suresh!

Comment: note: the messages expire every two days, so there's often a period (before I can renew the message) when it's completely gone.